# Running emacs remotely from a MinGW window

Tags: bash, emacs

I have a windows machine on which I have MinGW installed. I open up a shell and ssh to a remote machine and start emacs there. Emacs opens up fine in my local window and the basic functionality (including my keyboard map and some macros, and Lisp file editing) seems to run fine. However, I am unable to access the emacs top line menu, text selection using either clicking the mouse and dragging or moving the cursor and S-DOWN/UP-ARROW and dragging doesn't work, C-UP-ARROW to move over blocks doesn't work, etc (all these work fine when I am using the remote machine from a local terminal connected to it). I read elsewhere that the problem sometimes is that emacs is not running in a login shell. However I started a bash --login upon sshing into the machine and then ran emacs but that makes no difference. I also tried sourcing .bash_profile and .bashrc before starting emacs.

Anyone have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You are running emacs in a vanilla terminal session.  It doesn't know about your mouse. I'm a little rusty on ssh/telnet but, afaik, it doesn't have the protocol to communicate such actions.  The menu can be accessed in a relatively useless manner by pressing F10 if your system and all the intervening software cooperate.

In such a situation, you need to know the emacs key sequences for what you want to do.